# How cold is it acceptable for a Shetland Sheepdog to stay in for 2 to 4 hours?

Tags: dogs, safety, weather

We have a Shetland Sheepdog that we keep indoors. When we leave the house, we put him out, or put him in his crate.

Suppose it is 10 °F (-12 °C) and not wet. Is this a safe temperature for several hours outside?

How about 20 °F (-7 °C) or 0 °F (-18 °C)? How do you know?

We have been playing it safe, but he hates the crate, and I don't want to confine him unnecessarily.